# Allow restricted bash users to run specific python script

Tags: bash, python, restricted-access

I need to allow a particular user to run a specific python script. This user has access to a restricted bash which for now allows only the `clear` command.
Usually, the script would be run through `python3 script_name.py`. In this case, the goal is to restrict the users capabilities at the maximum. Thus, I would like to not give access to the `python3` command to the user.
Is there a way to restrict the use of the `python3` command to the specific `python3 script_name.py` or a way to automatically and temporarily switch user to an authorized one, run the script, and then switch back to the original user?
Thanks a lot!

Edit:
While searching further information regarding the capabilities of the restricted shell and its configuration, I found [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html), on which is said:

> When a command that is found to be a shell script is executed (see Shell Scripts), rbash turns off any restrictions in the shell spawned to execute the script.

Does this mean that creating a `.sh` file containing `python3 script_name.py` in the base folder for the user and adding the execution rights to this file should solve my issue? It is after all a shell script and thus should be exempted from restrictions.

Update:
While a script didn't solve my issue, [@muru](https://askubuntu/users/158442/muru) pointed me to a functional workaround.
I created a "launcher.py" executable file in the user's commands location containing only the following:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys
sys.path.insert([1], <path_to_actual_script>)

import <actual_script>
```

This allows the user to run the `launcher.py` command while not directly having access to the program.

Comment: Yes, using a script should avoid the issue, since the assumption is that you have vetted all scripts available for the restricted user. However, why not just make the script executable and use `#! /usr/bin/python3` as the shebang?

Comment: I'll try both methods, and i'll let you know which works and which doesn't. In case your solution works, you might want to post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Turns out using a script returns the same error as using the `python3` command directly, it doesn't work. Instead, I worked with what you recommended, I explain it in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is posible in theory. You have to:

1. Install firejail - sandbox in Ubuntu. It is suitable for apps provided in deb and appimage packages;
2. Create custom firejail profile for bash (restricted to use `sudo`, `python3` and `script_name.py`);
3. Create script `restricted_bash.sh` - it has to start bash in firejail with custom bash profile;
4. Change user shell in `/etc/passwd` to `restricted_bash.sh`;
5. Modify `script_name.py`: add `#!/usr/bin/python3` as first line.

Note: This is not tested!

Note: The disadwantage is that you have give user access to the `python3` - is normal because firejail restrictions are destiny and probably can not be escalated on demand (e.g. when you run `script_name.py`).

Note: bash have many build in commands, and you can not disable them in that way. In order to drop them all you will have to use other shell or even create custom restricted shell.

Comment: Regarding firejail, I am not sure what it does, especially after reading your note stating that the user would be given access to the `python3` command. I am using a restricted shell already to limit the set of commands accessible to the user to `clear` only, so adding `python3` wouldn't be difficult, although this is something I would like to avoid. I will look further into the possibilities that a restricted shell can provide.

Comment: Explanation: firejail is sandbox in Ubuntu. It is suitable for apps provided in deb and appimage packages. snap packages canot work with firejail. flatpack packages probably canot work with firejail. The advantage of firejail is simplicity and flexibility - this is oposite to snap which is beyond of user control.

Comment: I am not sure how this would solve my issue at hand here, but I'll keep this in mind for future applications! Do you have an idea on how this would restrict the use of the `python3` command?

Comment: No, I have no idea how to use `python3`  without aces it.